# Overlapping the parent layout with transperent background-color except highlighted points

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

There are several clickable views (buttons, checkboxes, etc) in my app. I want to familiarize the users with the purpose of some views, meaning why and when to use them. So that, I want to create one-time-only intro for some views.

I think the best way to do this is to **highlight the view** and **at the same time show toast-like info-box**.

Here's is the example of what I want to achieve (see below screenshot of [Fabulous app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.thefabulous.app&hl=en)). 
[image: Fabulous app. Intro for the purpose of the checkbox]

In the above example the whole screen is covered by transperent gray background while checkbox and toast-like info-box is highlighted with white color.

How can I create similar transperent background highlighting some views?